# How to create a method for saving a file and returning it as object ready for editing Android

Tags: android, file

I have a problem with creating a save to file. When I try to save the string to android it results in the string being not fully saved or not saved at all. The file needs to be created because it doesn't exist in the desired file path so that's another issue which I think could be easily fixed by creating this method. Help would be appreciated. The current method needs to be filled in but I have no idea how to go about it to get the file ready for reading straight away.

```
public File saveFile(String contents, String file) {


        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the path you could use this code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder/");

if (!dir.exists()) {
    if(dir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Path to " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " sucessfully created");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Path to " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " could not be created!");
    }
}
```

and storing the actual content could happen with something like this:

```
    File outFile = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Folder/", file);

    BufferedOutputStream mBOS = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(accelValFile));
    try {
        mBOS.write(contents.getBytes("utf-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and don't forget to put the following into your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But i don't understand why this method should return a file...

Comment: The file needs to be used for serializer for XML which doesn't accept strings but I have a string that stores XML file which is sent from a server.